# I have an android application where I can see that main activity is exported and there are no permissions set on that

Tags: android, security, automated-tests, opentest

I have an android application where I can see that main activity is exported and there are no permissions set on that. Is it a vulnerability or it is a normal behaviour?

Comment: Most likely, that is normal behavior. However, since you elected not to provide a [mcve], we are having to guess at what you mean by "main activity".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.